# Сумма квадратов помогите решить

Tags: python-3.x

Сумма квадратов
Напишите программу, которая по данному натуральному числу N вычисляет сумму следующего выражения: 12 + 2 2 + 33 + … + n2.

Входные данные: вводится единственное натуральное число n, не превосходящее 100.

Выходные данные: необходимо вывести вычисленную сумму

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 1):

решайте в лоб:

1. запросить у пользователя `N` через функцию `input()`
2. преобразовать ввод пользователя из строки в число через функцию `int()`
3. пройтись в цикле от `1` до `N` включительно через команду `for` и функцию `range(1, N + 1)`
4. вычислить квадрат через `x**2` или `x*x`
5. сложить с результатом через `res +=`
6. вывести результат через функцию `print()`

вообще такая программа пишется после 5 минутного - 2 часового (в зависимости он навыков) прочтения документации по питону